# How can gas be cooled to liquid by expansion?

Tags: thermodynamics, gas, cooling, liquid-state

My friend works at a gas company and told me that in order to cool gas to low temperatures to form a liquid, they compress the gas and then cool it to say -10 degrees C, then let it expand and it gets even colder as it expands and turns into a liquid. He said it is because PV=nRT. But it seems to me that when you increase the volume to let it expand, the pressure goes down, and if they happen in the right way the temperature would just stay the same. How can we be sure that as we increase V, P decreases more rapidly to make the left hand side and ultimately T, smaller. Or is this the wrong first principle to use to understand this process?

Comment: This process involves expanding gas and clever heat transfer.  A brief article on the process can be found at this site: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hampson%E2%80%93Linde_cycle.

Answer (score 1):

Gas molecules are not ideal and have a force of attraction between them.
In the act of separation (pressure reduction) work is done by the gas molecules against the forces of attraction when separating (their potential energy increases) and this results in a reduction in the thermal kinetic energy of the molecules ie the temperature drops.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to cool a gas by expansion. The two main ways are adiabatic expansion and the Joule-Kelvin process (also called throttling). There are gas liquification plants based on both ideas.

In adiabatic expansion there is no heat flow either in or out. As the gas expands it pushes outwards on its boundary (say, a piston), doing work. Therefore its internal energy decreases. In the absence of heat flowing in, the temperature must fall. This kind of cooling works for any gas, including the ideal gas.

In Joule-Kelvin expansion the gas is pushed through a narrow constriction, again in conditions of thermal isolation. In this process you can in principle get either cooling or heating, depending on the conditions. For an ideal gas you would not get either cooling or heating. For any real gas, however, at high enough pressure and starting from the low enough temperature (called inversion temperature) you can get cooling. This is widely used for gas liquification in a process called Linde process.

The cooling effect in Joule-Kelvin expansion can be seen ultimately as an expression of the attractive forces between molecules. If you start at high pressure with the molecules close together, then as the gas expands they move apart and thus go to higher separation, where their potential energy is higher. As they do this their kinetic energy falls by some modest but useful amount.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the pressure-enthalpy diagram of various substances, such as water.  If you control the pressurization and cooling properly, you will arrive at a point on the p-H diagram to the left of the saturation envelope.  If you then flash the gas through a valve (i.e., as in a continuous flow process), the enthalpy per unit mass will remain constant (according to the open system version of the 1st law of thermodynamics) while the pressure drops, and you will cross into the interior of the saturation envelope.  The flashed mixture will be a combination of saturated vapor and saturated liquid at the final pressure.  So the trick is (1) above critical temperature, increase pressure above critical pressure (2) cool at constant pressure to below critical temperature.